# How do you write to a folder with spaces in it?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, command-line

I've got a bunch of simple SSIS packages that output SQL data to excel, then I rename the files and move them out to the end user.

Some of them use file paths with spaces in them, and they aren't excited about using new folders.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
    declare @date varchar(25),
    @sql varchar(1000)

    set @date = cast(datepart(month, current_timestamp) as varchar(2)) + '_' +  cast(datepart(day, current_timestamp) as varchar(2)) + '_' +  cast(datepart(year, current_timestamp) as varchar(4))
    print @date

    set @sql = 'copy D:\Data\ED_72.xlsx \\ehsintra3\ED_72_weekly\ED_72_' + @date + '.xlsx';
    print @sql

    exec  xp_cmdshell @sql
```

but it wouldnt work without the underscores.

**Question** how can I make this work without underscores?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should (pretty much always) enclose paths inside quotation marks.  So, like this:

```
declare @date varchar(25),
@sql varchar(1000);

set @date = cast(datepart(month, current_timestamp) as varchar(2)) + ' ' +  cast(datepart(day, current_timestamp) as varchar(2)) + ' ' +  cast(datepart(year, current_timestamp) as varchar(4));
print @date;

set @sql = 'copy "D:\Data\ED_72.xlsx" "\\ehsintra3\ED 72 weekly\ED 72 ' + @date + '.xlsx"';
print @sql;

exec  xp_cmdshell @sql;
```

Putting paths inside quotation marks ensures the command-processor can understand where a path starts and ends.

Also, instead of using `copy` you probably want to look at either `robocopy` or `xcopy`.  The `copy` command is brutally weak and frail.

Also, a minor note, add semi-colons to the end of your statements in T-SQL.

Answer (score 6):

The other approach is to use the File System Task within SSIS itself. It handles "complex" path and file names without the rigmarole and risks of `xp_cmdshell` escaping.

What risk? There's a limit on double quoted arguments.

See also [Escaping command parameters passed to xp_cmdshell to dtexec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3760537) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Not sure if "limit" is the right word. Perhaps it is, but I'd say it's rather a peculiarity of how cmd processes double quotes in a command line. I believe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474738/batch-file-for-f-doesnt-work-if-path-has-spaces) is essentially about the same problem and [jeb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474738/batch-file-for-f-doesnt-work-if-path-has-spaces/6878926#6878926) explains what is going on.

Comment: Agreed.  And you can use Script tasks + Package/Project variables to make dynamic paths if needed.